# Compass API for Windows Phone 7 (Mango)

Tags: silverlight-4.0, xna-4.0, windows-phone-7

Is there  any API available to access the compass hardware in WP7 (Mango)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can use the [Compass](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br225705) class. You can get sample code showing how to read the compass in the [Raw Sensor Data Sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Raw-Sensor-Data-Sample-d84e124d#content) or this ['How To'](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh202974(v=vs.105).aspx).